# Calculation on every pair from grouped data.frame

Tags: r, dplyr

My question is about performing a calculation between each pair of groups in a data.frame, I'd like it to be more vectorized.

I have a data.frame that has a consists of the following columns: `Location` , `Sample` , `Var1`, and `Var2`. I'd like to find the closet match for each `Sample` for each pair of `Location`s for both `Var1` and `Var2`.

I can accomplish this for one pair of locations as such:

```
df0 <- data.frame(Location = rep(c("A", "B", "C"), each =30), 
                 Sample = rep(c(1:30), times =3),
                 Var1 = sample(1:25, 90, replace =T),
                 Var2 = sample(1:25, 90, replace=T))
df00 <- data.frame(Location = rep(c("A", "B", "C"), each =30), 
                 Sample = rep(c(31:60), times =3),
                 Var1 = sample(1:100, 90, replace =T),
                 Var2 = sample(1:100, 90, replace=T))
df000 <- rbind(df0, df00)
df <- sample_n(df000, 100) # data

dfl <- df %>% gather(VAR, value, 3:4)

df1 <- dfl %>% filter(Location == "A")
df2 <- dfl %>% filter(Location == "B")
df3 <- merge(df1, df2, by = c("VAR"), all.x = TRUE, allow.cartesian=TRUE)
df3 <- df3 %>% mutate(DIFF = abs(value.x-value.y))
result <- df3 %>% group_by(VAR, Sample.x) %>% top_n(-1, DIFF)
```

I tried other possibilities such as using `dplyr::spread` but could not avoid the "Error: Duplicate identifiers for rows" or columns half filled with NA.

Is there a more clean and automated way to do this for each possible group pair? I'd like to avoid the manual subset and merge routine for each pair.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to create the pairwise combination of 'Location' with `combn` and then do the other steps as in the OP's code

```
 library(tidyverse)
 df %>% 
    # get the unique elements of Location
    distinct(Location) %>% 
    # pull the column as a vector
    pull %>% 
    # it is factor, so convert it to character
    as.character %>% 
    # get the pairwise combinations in a list
    combn(m = 2, simplify = FALSE) %>%
    # loop through the list with map and do the full_join
    # with the long format data df1
    map(~ full_join(df1 %>% 
                      filter(Location == first(.x)), 
                    df1 %>% 
                      filter(Location == last(.x)), by = "VAR") %>% 
             # create a column of absolute difference
             mutate(DIFF = abs(value.x - value.y)) %>%
             # grouped by VAR, Sample.x
             group_by(VAR, Sample.x) %>%
             # apply the top_n with wt as DIFF
             top_n(-1, DIFF))
```

---

Also, as the OP mentioned about automatically picking up instead of doing double `filter` (not clear about the expected output though)

```
df %>% 
   distinct(Location) %>%
   pull %>%
   as.character %>% 
   combn(m = 2, simplify = FALSE) %>% 
   map(~ df1 %>% 
             # change here i.e. filter both the Locations
             filter(Location %in% .x) %>% 
             # spread it to wide format
             spread(Location, value, fill = 0) %>% 
             # create the DIFF column by taking the differene
             mutate(DIFF = abs(!! rlang::sym(first(.x)) - 
                              !! rlang::sym(last(.x)))) %>% 
             group_by(VAR, Sample) %>% 
             top_n(-1, DIFF))
```

Comment: the first solution produces the desired result. Doing a double filter is fine within in a piped procedure.

Comment: @nofunsally  Thanks, the second was not clear to me.  In the first, there is a full_join and it can be replixated in the second