# Find closest match, then next closest, between groups until a specified number of matches has been made

Tags: r, dplyr

I'd like to find the closest match (smallest difference) of a variable between two groups, but if the closest match has already been made, move on to the next closest match, until n number of matches have been made.

I used the code from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55183346/1670053) (below) to find the closest match of a `value` between `Samples`for each pairwise grouping of all groups (i.e. `Location` by `VAR`).

However, there are many repeats, and the top match for `Sample.x` 1, 2, and 3, might all be `Sample.y` 1.

What I'd like to instead is find the next closest match for `Sample.x` 2, then 3, etc. until I specified number of distinct (`Sample.x`-`Sample.y`) matches have been made. But the order of `Sample.x` is not important, I'm just looking for the top n matches between `Sample.x` and `Sample.y` for a given grouping.

I attempted to do this with `dplyr::distinct` as shown below. But I am unsure how to use the distinct entries for `Sample.y` to filter the dataframe and then again by smallest `DIFF`. However, this won't necessarily result in unique `Sample` pairings.

Is there a smart way to accomplish this in R with dplyr? Is there a name for this type of operation?

```
 df01 <- data.frame(Location = rep(c("A", "C"), each =10), 
                   Sample = rep(c(1:10), times =2),
                   Var1 =  signif(runif(20, 55, 58), digits=4),
                   Var2 = rep(c(1:10), times =2)) 
df001 <- data.frame(Location = rep(c("B"), each =10), 
                    Sample = rep(c(1:10), times =1),
                    Var1 = c(1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.6, 56, 110.1, 111.6, 111.7, 111.8, 120.5),
                    Var2 = c(1.5, 10.1, 10.2, 11.7, 12.5, 13.6, 14.4, 18.1, 20.9, 21.3))
df <- rbind(df01, df001)
dfl <- df %>% gather(VAR, value, 3:4)

df.result <- df %>% 
  # get the unique elements of Location
  distinct(Location) %>% 
  # pull the column as a vector
  pull %>% 
  # it is factor, so convert it to character
  as.character %>% 
  # get the pairwise combinations in a list
  combn(m = 2, simplify = FALSE) %>%
  # loop through the list with map and do the full_join
  # with the long format data dfl
  map(~ full_join(dfl %>% 
                    filter(Location == first(.x)), 
                  dfl %>% 
                    filter(Location == last(.x)), by = "VAR") %>% 
        # create a column of absolute difference
        mutate(DIFF = abs(value.x - value.y)) %>%
        # grouped by VAR, Sample.x
        group_by(VAR, Sample.x) %>%
        # apply the top_n with wt as DIFF
        # here I choose 5, 
        # and then hope that this is enough to get a smaller n of final matches
        top_n(-5, DIFF) %>%
        mutate(GG = paste(Location.x, Location.y, sep="-")))

res1 <- rbindlist(df.result)
res2 <- res1 %>% group_by(GG, VAR) %>% distinct(Sample.y)    
res3 <- res2 %>% group_by(GG, VAR) %>% top_n(-2, DIFF)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I edit the code above that produces `df.result` by removing the line `top_n(-5, DIFF) %>%`. Now `res1` contains all matches of `Sample.x` and `Sample.y`.

Then I used the `res1` in the code below. This probably is not perfect, but what it does is finds the closest `Sample.y` match for the first entry of `Sample.x`. Then both of these `Samples` are filtered from the dataframe. The matching repeats until matches are found for every unique value of `Sample.y`. The result might differ depending which match was made first.

```
  fun <- function(df) {
  HowMany <- length(unique(df$Sample.y))
  i <- 1
  MyList_FF <- list()
  df_f <- df
  while (i <= HowMany){
    res1 <- df_f %>%
      group_by(grp, VAR, Sample.x) %>%
      filter(DIFF == min(DIFF)) %>%
      ungroup() %>%
      mutate(Rank1 = dense_rank(DIFF))

    res2 <- res1 %>% group_by(grp, VAR) %>% filter(rank(Rank1, ties.method="first")==1)

    SY <- as.numeric(res2$Sample.y)
    SX <- as.numeric(res2$Sample.x)
    res3 <- df_f %>% filter(Sample.y != SY) # filter Sample.y
    res4 <- res3 %>% filter(Sample.x != SX) # filter Sample.x
    df_f <- res4

    MyList_FF[[i]] <- res2

    i <- i + 1
  }
  do.call("rbind", MyList_FF) # https://stackoverflow.com/a/55542822/1670053
}

df <- res1
MyResult <- df %>%
  dplyr::group_split(grp, VAR) %>%
  map_df(fun)
```